# Fix for poor HD playback using ATI or NVidia graphics

Tags: nvidia, video, ati, mplayer

Hi all I was wondering if any one had a fix for the poor HD playback of ubuntu I see many questions on here and google but no one seems to know.

Comment: It would be better if you could post this as an answer in the posts  that you see or edit this post to ask a question and write the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is a QA site and, as such, needs a QA format. Please reform into a question with an answer so that everyone can benefit. Thanks. Otherwise, this will have to be flagged for removal which would be a shame.

Comment: Im new to ask ubuntu so could some one just put a small explanation how I can make this post acceptable I just wanted to shear a great fix with the community or even another site I could post this on cheers

Comment: OK dont matter I reformatted it quite esaly in the end hope this is acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working just follow these steps.....

1 install mplayer

2 install smplayer frontend {in software center}

3 open smplayer

4 go to "OPTIONS" then "PREFRENCES" then "GENRAL"

5 if you have a nvidia card choose "OUTPUT DRIVER" and select "VDPAU" {for ATI or AMD choose xv (0 - ATI Radeon AVIVO video) I dont know if this will work as my card is nvidia but it should)

6 go to performance on the left hand side and set both local and streaming cache to 99999 (this may also fix dvd playback if you set that cache aswell}

7 check the box for "ALLOW HARD FRAME DROP" and set "LOOP FILTER" to skip only on HD

8 Set the "THREDS FOR DECODING OPTION TO THE NUMBER OF CORES YOUR CPU HAS IF YOU HAVE MORE THAN ONE CPU ADD UP ALL THE CORES FOR BEST PERFORMANCE"

9 Enjoy you HD movies again on ubuntu......

I have a pretty avrage machine heres my spec....

2x Pentium 4 ht 3 ghz

Stock dell power and motherboard

GFORCE 310 HDMI

24 inch full HD tv as a monitor

so any one with dule core cpu should have no problems getting this to work.

hope this helps someone out.