# Video/Graphic render issue with high quality (HD)

Tags: 11.10, drivers, video, graphics, ati

I have Dell N5010 with 512 MB Graphics (ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470), 4GB RAM, i3 2.53GHz, 15'4'' LED Display, Ubuntu 11.10.

When I open a HD video/movie with VLC, Rhytmbox, or Media Player (default) it hangs. I think this is a driver problem.

Is there any specific driver for dell N5010, I need ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470 driver for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily, the support for the hardware acceleration via GPU is not that good by default, is still considered experimental, also the AMD ATI CCC center, aka the panel control of your VGA, offers some tweaks to have a smoother desktop and playback.

Have a look at http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide for Ubuntu Precise Pangolin, the packages that can interest you are under this section http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Hardware_Video_Decode_Acceleration_.28EXPERIMENTAL.29 .

Be sure that you have the latest driver from AMD, the fglrx driver from the official repository are usually outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I just [posted a HD playback fix](https://askubuntu.com/q/159794/28369). If you're after drivers, open settings and select restricted drivers.